# Getting JSON files using cURL in C++, larger files are not appearing or are maybe just too large

Tags: c++, json, curl

I am trying to parse json files using libcurl then parsing with JSON for modern c++. However, when I try and get the json files from a url, then print it out as a string just to see, it successfully gets small ones like http://validate.jsontest.com/?json=%5BJSON-code-to-validate%5D, but fails and shows nothing on huge files like http://reddit.com/r/front.json

What exactly is happening here? I'm pretty sure the string type is large enough to hold all of it, is curl not able to handle it?

Here's the code I have

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <json.hpp>
#include <curl/curl.h>

namespace
{
    std::size_t callback(
            const char* in,
            std::size_t size,
            std::size_t num,
            std::string* out)
    {
        const std::size_t totalBytes(size * num);
        out->append(in, totalBytes);
        return totalBytes;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const std::string url("http://validate.jsontest.com/?json=%5BJSON-code-to-validate%5D");

    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

    // Set remote URL.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

    // Don't bother trying IPv6, which would increase DNS resolution time.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

    // Don't wait forever, time out after 10 seconds.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // Follow HTTP redirects if necessary.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    // Response information.
    int httpCode(0);
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> httpData(new std::string());

    // Hook up data handling function.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);

    // Hook up data container (will be passed as the last parameter to the
    // callback handling function).  Can be any pointer type, since it will
    // internally be passed as a void pointer.
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, httpData.get());

    // Run our HTTP GET command, capture the HTTP response code, and clean up.
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpCode);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    std::cout << *httpData << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I've looked at other related questions on this but none of them really helped.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is due to reddit.com API limitation. This can cause because of User-Agent header mostly. For more Info read Rules Section of https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API.

Any way testing purpose you can copy your browser User-agent and test once like this

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36");
```

If you want to use apis constantly you have to use OAuth2 to authorise your application with reddit.